# QDateTime usage in my Qt project causing issue during Daylight Savings?

Tags: qt5, qt5.1

I have created a project to read data before and after an event.

For example:
Let D1, D2, D3 be QDateTime objects:
Let D1 be one with a value of **2014-03-09T2:30:00**.
 
Let D2 be one with a value of **2014-03-09T1:30:00**.
Let D3 be one with a value of **2014-03-09T3:30:00**.

```
D1.date() will return QDate(2014,3,9).
D1.time() will return QTime(2,30).
D1.toString() will return “”.
(D1 > D2) is true.
(D1 < D2) is false.
(D1 > D3) is false.
(D1 < D3) is true.
(D1 == D1) is true.
D1.secsTo(X) is always 0.
X.secsTo(D1) is always 0, for all X.
```

In this case, D1.secsTo(X) is used to calculate the reports from 1:00 AM.  The DST effect occurs between 2-3 AM.

What do I need to do to correct for this transition?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdatetime.html#secsTo) claims that the QDateTime class should handle DST automatically, but this appears to be a bug in Qt.  I just tried with inputs you provided, and got 0 for the secsTo() method if either time was between 2-3 AM.  It provided a correct offset if I changed the times to be after 3 AM.

For example:

```
D1 = 2:30 AM
D2 = 2:45 AM
D1.secsTo(D2) gives 0

D1 = 3:30 AM
D2 = 3:45 AM
D1.secsTo(D2) gives 900
```

I filed a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-37805).

**Edit**

Your current solution should work once the bug is fixed.  Another solution for the meantime could be to convert your timestamps to UTC before doing any calculations.  The QDateTime class has a toUTC() method.  I think that should avoid DST problems completely.

Comment: Yes Thanks.The problem is seen when I tried to collect the data from the midnight the time 2 to 3 am is always zero for secsTo() and similarly for addSecs(), toString() if they are used with QDateTime objects.
I tested this scenario in the Pacific Time Zone (UTC-08:00)
Is there any suggestion to correct this transition.?